# Error when sending mails with Mandrill in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, mandrill

I'm having problems with an error when trying to send mails with my App with Mandrill.

I've seen a lot of people have this problem, and I'm sure it has to do with my mailer configuration. See if someone knows how to deal with this, because I'm desperate about it.

ERROR:

```
Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused - connect(2)):
```

#### production.rb

```
  # Config default action mailer
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => "localhost" }

  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address   => "smtp.mandrillapp.com",
    :port      => 587, 
    :enable_starttls_auto => true,
    :user_name => ENV["MANDRILL_USERNAME"],
    :password  => ENV["MANDRILL_PASSWORD"],
    :authentication => 'login',
    :domain => 'heroku.com'
  }

  # Setup for production - deliveries, no errors raised
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.default :charset => "utf-8"
```

Answer (score 0):

We use Mandrill in production like this:

```
#config/environments/production.rb
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address        => "smtp.mandrillapp.com",
    :port           => "587",
    :authentication => :plain,
    :user_name      => "username",
    :password       => "API key",
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

We literally have no other options for Heroku - I think you should remove the `default_url_options` and `domain` options